# When i try to refresh my page i have this error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

> error
>   .Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid shorthand property initializer angular.js:38 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.5/$injector/modul

This is my **app.js** code:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myapp", ["ngRoute"]);

myApp.controller("myController", function($scope){
console.log("This is app.js ...........");

$scope.users = [
    {username="John" , email="john@mail.com"},
    {username="Adam" , email="Adam@adam.com"}
];
});
```

This is my **index.html** code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
    <div class="container">

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right"
            data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Add Product</button>
        <h2>Product List</h2>



        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Index</th>
                    <th>UserName</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Edit</th>
                    <th>Delete</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
                    <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
                    <td>{{user.username}}</td>
                    <td>{{user.email}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal"
                            data-target="#myModalEdit">Edit</button>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal"
                            data-target="#myModalDelete">delete</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please read more about [**JavaScript Objects**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object), then try to re-write your code.

Comment: you are adding `"ngRoute"` module, but you don't have a script for it: `angular-route.js`

Comment: Can you mark it as answer so that it can help others as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fix `ng-app="myApp"` to `ng-app="myapp"` in html file. [check this plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/DUqZ7xwhOwydfkxtjMT8?p=preview)

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller("myController", function($scope){
console.log("This is app.js ...........");

$scope.users = [
    {username: "John" , email:"john@mail.com"},
    {username:"Adam" , email:"Adam@adam.com"}
];
});
```

Comment: @ShantoSiddiq: One suggestion: try to use `angular.js` rather than `angular.min.js` when you are developing. You'll get proper description of error in your console. `min` files doesn't provide good error explanation. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

That's not the way to declare an object. Replace = with :

```
$scope.users = [
    {username:"Shanto" , email:"shanto@gmail.com"},
    {username : "Adam" , email : "Adam@adam.com"}
];
```

Comment: I have changed that but still the same problem. this is found when i inspect the page in the console......                                          angular.js:38 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.5/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Anomod%5D%20